# How can I use the default parameter values of the constructor when there is no corresponding value to deserialise?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class which is instantiated both directly in the code and also by a deserialiser. Typically there will be a value for all constructor parameters present in the JSON representation of an ImmutablePropertyStore object - in this case things work as expected. However, sometimes there may be some or all values missing in the JSON representation. In this case, I would hope that json.NET would use the default parameters provided in the constructor. However, it appears to ignore those default parameters and instead instantiate the class with the missing values being set to the default value for that datatype - false, in the case of booleans.

The below example code illustrates the problem (in practice, there are a lot more properties):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ImmutablePropertyStore immutablePropertyStore = new ImmutablePropertyStore();
        Console.WriteLine(immutablePropertyStore);
        string jsonRepresentation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(immutablePropertyStore, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutablePropertyStore>(jsonRepresentation));

        // Desired output: Property A is 'True' and Property B is 'True'.     Actual Output: Property A is 'False' and Property B is 'True'.
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutablePropertyStore>("{\"PropertyB\": true}")); 

        // Desired output: Property A is 'True' and Property B is 'False'.     Actual Output: Property A is 'False' and Property B is 'False'.
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutablePropertyStore>("{}"));

    }
}

public class ImmutablePropertyStore
{
    public bool PropertyA { get; }
    public bool PropertyB { get; }

    public ImmutablePropertyStore(bool propertyA = true, bool propertyB = false)
    {
        PropertyA = propertyA;
        PropertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Property A is '{PropertyA}' and Property B is '{PropertyB}'.";
    }

}
```

or as a .NET fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ft7fGQ

I would like the final line of the output to be:

> Property A is 'True' and Property B is 'False'.

rather than:

> Property A is 'False' and Property B is 'False'.

How can I achieve this in a way that:

1. maintains the immutability of the class (no public setters) and
2. allows the default values to be specified in one place and used for both direct instantiation and instantiation via deserialisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom `JsonConverter`, alternatively make the constructor parameters for `ImmutablePropertyStore` be nullable and default their values to `null`. Then inside the ctor you can determine what the 'real' default value should be.

```
public ImmutablePropertyStore(bool? propertyA = null, bool? propertyB = null)
{
  PropertyA = propertyA ?? true;
  PropertyB = propertyB ?? false;
}
```

As you mentioned, the default values for a property type is used (`null` for nullable types) which is then converted to the correct 'real' value in the ctor.

The default values are not as apparent using this method but I'm not sure whether that will be an issue or not.

Comment: Seems to be the only answer that actually works when some values are missing but not all

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full use case, is this something like what you're looking for? Using `DefaultValue` attributes in conjunction with `JsonSerializerSettings`.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate
        };
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutablePropertyStore>("{}"));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutablePropertyStore>(@"{propertyB: ""true""}"));    
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutablePropertyStore>(@"{PropertyA: ""false"", PropertyB: ""true""}"));    
    }
}

public class ImmutablePropertyStore
{
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool PropertyA { get; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool PropertyB { get; }


    public ImmutablePropertyStore(bool propertyA, bool propertyB)
    {
        PropertyA = propertyA;
        PropertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Property A is '{PropertyA}' and Property B is '{PropertyB}'.";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Property A is 'True' and Property B is 'False'.
Property A is 'True' and Property B is 'True'.
Property A is 'False' and Property B is 'True'.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this will prevent ImmutablePropertyStore from being instantiated directly with any missing arguments ('new ImmutablePropertyStore()' would no longer compile, for example). In my use case, I need the default values to be used for both direct instantiation and instantiation via deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I see these issues,

- In that making a class immutable is somewhat of a coding exercise, for the class is not sealed and if a consumer wanted to get the object and change it, well that could be done.
- Now you have only two default values, but what if there are more? The complexity of it all is exponential as it grows.

---

**Answer**

I suggest that you change design and make a base class with all the properties mutable and that will be the target of any deserialization operation (*since mutable properties play well with deserialization*). Then a consumer will get the immutable instance via covert/copy/reflect it from that base class.

```
var bse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MutablePropertyStore>("{ 'PropertyB' : true }");
Console.WriteLine("Base:    " +  bse.ToString());   

var derived = new ImmutablePropertyStore(bse);              
Console.WriteLine("Derived: " + derived.ToString());
```

**Result**

```
Base:    Property A is 'True' and Property B is 'True'.
Derived: Property A is 'True' and Property B is 'True'.
```

---

Example [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kn4YGM)

**Code**

```
public sealed class ImmutablePropertyStore : MutablePropertyStore
{
    public new bool PropertyA { get; private set; }
    public new bool PropertyB { get; private set; }

    public ImmutablePropertyStore() { }

    public ImmutablePropertyStore(MutablePropertyStore ms)
    {
        PropertyA = ms.PropertyA;
        PropertyB = ms.PropertyB;
    }

    public ImmutablePropertyStore(bool propertyA = true, bool propertyB = false)
    {
        PropertyA = propertyA;
        PropertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
        => $"Property A is '{PropertyA}' and Property B is '{PropertyB}'."; 
}

public class MutablePropertyStore
{
    public virtual bool PropertyA { get; set;}
    public virtual bool PropertyB { get; set;}

    // Set all defaults here
    public MutablePropertyStore() { PropertyA = true; }

    public override string ToString() 
        => $"Property A is '{PropertyA}' and Property B is '{PropertyB}'.";      

}
```

Comment: I think this solution is probably overkill for my particular situation - sealing the class is probably a good idea, though. Also, I would suggest the complexity (depending on how it's defined) remains constant and the size of the class would grow linearly as more properties are added. Nothing would grow exponentially.